# Rerouting sub paths to a main path in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my routes file I am trying to achieve the following.

```
const routes: Routes = [{ ...
{ path: '', component: MainComponent, children: [
    { path: 'routeA', component: ComponentA },
    { path: 'routeA/subA', component: ComponentAA},
    { path: 'routeA/subB', component: ComponentAB},
    { path: 'routeA/**', redirectTo: 'routeA'}
]}, ...}
```

The intention being that routeA/ will redirect back to routeA, but the above code doesnt achieve the intended effect.

Comment: are you trying to achieve if `routeA/xyz` is not found then redirect to `routeA` route? try to add more info to understand this issue

Comment: otherwise just remove `routeA/**` and replace it with `**` this will then redirect any traffic not found to `routeA`